# Doctrine find() and querybuilder() return different result in PHPUnit test

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit

With Doctrine and Symfony in my PHPUnit test method :

```
// Change username for user #1 (Sheriff Woody to Chuck Norris)
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Update')->form([
    'user[username]' => 'Chuck Norris',
]);
$client->submit($form);

// Find user #1
$user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find(1);
dump($user); // Username = "Sheriff Woody"

$user = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from(User::class, 'user')
        ->andWhere('user.id = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', 1)
        ->select('
            user
        ')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
dump($user); // Username = "Chuck Norris"
```

Why my two methods to fetch the user #1 return different results ?

Comment: This seems like a caching issue to me. Can you verify this assumption by calling `$em->clear` before the first query to see if clearing the cache causes the right result to be returned? Furthermore, can you provide more details about your problem? Are you calling both queries in the same test case? Could you provide your full test case(s) and controller action?

Comment: Have you tried to move `->select()` before `->from()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### diagnosis / explanation

I *assume** you already created the User object you're editing via crawler before in that function and checked that it is there. This leads to it being a managed entity.

It is in the nature of data, to not sync itself magically with the database, but some automatism must be in place or some method executed to sync it.

The `find()` method will always try to use the cache (unless explicitly turned off, also see side note). <strike>The query builder won't, if you explicitly call `getResult()` (or one of its varieties), since you explicitly want a query to be executed.</strike> Executing a different query might lead to the cache not being hit, producing the current result. (it should update the first user object though ...) [updated, due to comment from  Arno Hilke]

*((( side note: Keeping objects in sync is **hard**. It's mainly about having consistency in the database, but all of [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) is wanted. Any process talking to the database should assume, that it only is working with the state at the moment of its first query, and is the only user of the database. Unless additional constraints must be met and inconsistent reads can occur, in which case isolation levels should be raised (See also: transactions or more precisely: isolation). So, automatically syncing is usually not wanted. Doctrine uses certain assumptions for performance gains (mainly: isolation / locking is optimistic). However, in your particular case, all of those things are of no actual concern... since you actually **want** a [non-repeatable read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Non-repeatable_reads). )))*

*(* otherwise, the behavior you're seeing would be **really** unexpected)*

#### solution

One easy solution would be, to actively and explicitly **sync** the data from the database by either calling `$em->refresh($user)`, or - before fetching the user again - to call `$em->clear()`, which will **detach all** entities (clearing the cache, which might have a noticable performance impact) and allowing you to call `find` again with the proper results being returned.

Please note, that detaching entities means, that any object previously returned from the entity manager should be discarded and fetched again (not via refresh).

#### alternate solution 1 - everything is requests

instead of checking the database, you could instead do a different request to a page that displays the user's name and checks that it has changed.

#### alternate solution 2 - using only one entity manager

using only one entity manager (that is: sharing the entity manager / database in the unit test with the server on the request) may be a reasonable solution, but it comes with its own set of problems. mainly omitted commits and flushes may avoid detection.

#### alternate solution 3 - using multiple entity managers

using one entity manager to set up the test, since the server is using a new entity manager to perform its work, you should theoretically - to do this actually properly - create yet another entity manager to check the server's behavior.

comment: the alternate solutions 1,2 and 3 would work with the highest isolation level, the initial solution probably wouldn't.

Comment: It is not correct that the query builder does not use the cache. I used the exact same query builder as in the question and I do get the cached result.

Comment: @ArnoHilke so you're saying you can't reproduce the problem? that would be even worse. however, you're probably right to some extent, because query builder queries can be cached. I just assumed that in this specific case it was not (otherwise the same result would have occured)

Comment: Yes, I tried to reproduce the problem with my own user entity and the exact queries provided in the question. In my test case, I update the user and call both queries. In that test, I get the old/cached/wrong result for both. When calling `$em->clear()` before the queries, I get the correct result for both. That's why I asked for more information, because I could not reproduce the behaviour described in the question. Do you experience a different behaviour (with the query builder as described in the question)? In that case, it could also be a difference in doctrine versions.

Comment: @ArnoHilke another reason could be a race condition... according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html the http client is asynchronous, so technically, the server could be slow and the test's entity manager could return faster. if then, client and server share the same entity manager (it's very convenient at times) the first call to the entity manager could return the old object, and the cache gets updated and the second query returns the new object that was put there from the server ...

Comment: I think it would be worth noting the difference between "_entity manager's in-memory state/cache_" and "[Doctrine explicit caching](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/caching.html#caching)" in that only `find` method would fetch data from the "_in-memory state/cache_" using the "_identity mapping_", whereas all `find`, `QueryBuilder`, `findBy` variants would fetch from the explicit cache. 
As a result, in case of no explicit caching, I noticed that both `QueryBuilder` and `findBy` variants would always try to fetch data from the database.